# Utility class for formatting

Tags: java, class, utility

I have implemented a utility class called FormatUtils (final with static methods) that converts data from Employee objects into a usable format (e.g. stripping '$' signs off strings and parsing them as doubles, reformatting names into first and last names). Now, somewhere in my code, I need a method that formats lots of Employee data fields for output as a single string (sent later to stdout). Does it make sense to put it in this utility class when it is probably only going to be needed for use with Employee objects, rather than having general purpose?

Comment: Sounds like you should move it to `Employee#toString()`.

Comment: sounds like a `employee.toString()` method

Comment: Sounds like a plan! Thanks

Comment: Maybe is just me, but I don't think is a good idea that your entity package depends on utility package. An option may be having `Employee#toString` (as stated by 2 people) but maybe (just maybe) you have another class that could receive the `Employee` object and return a `String` from it.

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably move the methods to format a single `Employee` into the `Employee` class itself.  If there's different/additional formatting that needs to be done for a list of employees (like row & column headings, for example), I might put that in a utility method (or class, if it needs to be reused).

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `Employee#toString()` to format it for human readers; use that method for debugging only. Otherwise, you might not be able to use anything in the class to show its status in the debugger.  I know the primitive wrappers and enums use `toString()` for that, but that's mostly for using them with string concatenation.

What does "stripping '$' signs off strings and parsing them as doubles" mean? Are you storing the employee's salary as a String?  Don't do that.  By and large, currency values should be `BigDecimal` or `BigInteger` objects.  You put the dollar signs in when formatting using `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance()`.  It makes database work easier too.

If you are busy splitting names into first and last names, you really need a `Name` class, and you should provide formatters for that.  For JPA work, you can make the Name instance variable`@Embeddable`.

You can give the `Employee` class format methods, or you can have your class implement `java.util.Formattable`, possibly accepting the *alternative* formatting flag. You could even use 'getless programming' and give `Employee` methods like:

```
public void writeToFormally(final Appendable a) {...}
public void writeToSimply(final Appendable a) {...}
```